# Separating a column in multiple columns in R

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```
df1<-read.table(text= "Group
11Z-23456
12B-10000
22M-2000
12M-1100
33G-100",header=TRUE)
```

I want to get this data:

```
A   B   C   Code
1   1   Z   23456
1   2   B   10000
2   2   M   2000
1   2   M   1100
3   3   G   100
```

As you can see from my data, I want to separate the values in the Group  This is just an small sample, but please consider for a large sample.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you spell out the logic so it's clear how "112M" becomes 11, 2, M but "313G" becomes 3, 13, G?

Comment: @use2020 so you want R to be able to take "222P" and guess whether you meant "22 2 P" or "2 22 P" without any other information, when either of these is a possibility? How would you even know when it was right?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R code that you can have a try

```
l <- strsplit(as.character(df1$Group),split = "-")
dfout <- setNames(data.frame(t(mapply(c, strsplit(sapply(l, `[[`,1),split = ""),lapply(l, `[[`,2)))),
                  c("A","B","C","Code"))
```

or using `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  separate(Group,c("X","Code"),sep = "-") %>% 
  separate(X,c("A","B","C"),sep = 1:3)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  A B C  Code
1 1 1 Z 23456
2 1 2 B 10000
3 2 2 M  2000
4 1 2 M  1100
5 3 3 G   100
```

Comment: Thank you, can we make the codes shorter/ easier using tidyverse,

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[, c("ABC", "Code") := tstrsplit(Group, "-")]
df1[, c("A", "B", "C") := tstrsplit(ABC, "")]
df1[, c("ABC", "Group") := NULL]
df1
#     Code A B C
# 1: 23456 1 1 Z
# 2: 10000 1 2 B
# 3:  2000 2 2 M
# 4:  1100 1 2 M
# 5:   100 3 3 G
```